# how i can setting service to sending email with other external email service?

Tags: apex-email-service

i want to integration salesforce with my email service. I had the idea to send an email automation via my email service. But i don't know how to or salesforce can make it. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to relay Salesforce emails through your own email server? 
Take a look at the following link for more information on that: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_relay.htm&language=en

If you are using Lightning Experience, you could also enable email to be send over Office 365 or Gmail: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_enable_send_through_external.htm

This however only works for email sent by the users manually, and they still have the choice to use standard SF email. Automatically sent emails through workflows and apex will still be handled by the standard SF mailserver.